# AWS - Run a lambda for each s3 event

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a batch that parses an XMl file and inserts it into the database.
The batch is in Spring-Batch Java.
When I drop a file on an S3, a trigger launches a lambda that executes my batch (S3 event).

The parsing of an XML takes about 5 minutes (Lambda limit to 15 minutes is perfect), the problem is that at the end of the processing SpringBatch stops and will not be able to process new XML.

My problem: I can have several files that are dropped a few seconds apart and I would like each s3 event to launch a new lambda.

Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: Could you share CloudWatch logs?

Answer (score 0):

When you recieve your batch, you can add each message from the batch to an sqs queue.  Create another lambda that consumes that queue (you can do this with an SQS trigger), with a batch size of 1.  This way your consumer lambda will only process one file.  You can make it scale to process all of them in parallel this way as well, which might be better for you depending on your situation.